# Assigned variable value does not match API response value

Tags: objective-c

I am returning data from the web and assigning those API values to variables that I have created. After I run the application I've noticed that values from API response do not match the variables. I have the following:

```
NSInteger someNumber = apiDictionary[@"SomeKey"];
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
     SomeKey = 0;
}
```

I set a breakpoint to look at the response and get '0' just as expected, but when I check the value stored in the variable it shows '2'. I also tried using an Int data type and I end up with '-23432340'.

Comment: try with NSNumber instead of NSInteger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deserialize the JSON, it's going to give you back an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` of actual object types (scalar types can't be stored in Cocoa collections).  So, your dictionary will contain an `NSNumber` for the key `@"SomeKey"`, not an `NSInteger`.

You can request a scalar value from the object, if so needed.  E.g.: the simplest way to make your code work would be to do this:

```
NSInteger someNumber = [apiDictionary[@"SomeKey"] integerValue];
```

Comment: Yes, this was the answer. Thanks!